# does javascript/typescript support here-documents?

Tags: javascript, typescript, heredoc

does javascript (or typescript) support here-documents/heredoc?

essentially i want to add documentation/comments to the end of my scripts, without having to use block commenting syntax.

even if it's not specifically here-document support, is there any solution/workaround for adding info to the end of a script that is ignored by the interpreter?

e.g. `__END__` in ruby/python, or `<<EOF` in php

i have tried using backticks to surround documentation, but if there are code examples that use backticks for string interpolation, it breaks

Comment: Heredoc is not about adding documentation/comments, but is about multiline string literals.  And it is not ignored by interpreter.

Comment: Python doesn't have heredocs like that.

Comment: As @AKX said, Python doesn't have `__END__` syntax.  Probably you meant Perl.  Also, `<<EOF` syntax in PHP is not the same as it starts multi-line string literal.  Backticks in Javascript work similar to `<<EOF` in PHP, i.e. don't do what you want.  There is no direct analogue for `__END__` neither in Python/PHP nor in Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: No, neither JavaScript or TypeScript has anything like heredocs built in.

If you're willing to break standard, you could invent a heredoc-like syntax and write some amount of Babel code to transform it.

I'd just use block comments, maybe with a special header you can process, such as `/*@` or `/*!` ...

Comment: do those comment headers already exist, or are you suggesting them as custom ones to add support for? i wasn't able to find info about them if they already exist

Comment: `/*!` headers generally aren't removed by minifiers, `/**` tends to be for documentation (JSDoc).